# Python: continue loop in one string if

Tags: python, for-loop

This is example of abstract code (my task is not get unique items)

```
lst = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
uniq = []
for i in lst:
    if i in uniq:
        continue
    uniq.append(i)
    print(str(i))  # other useful code
```

I want write single-string-if with continue operator in else statement. Example

```
uniq.append(i) if i not in uniq else continue
```

How to do it right?

Comment: just use `uniq = list(set(lst))`

Comment: my task is not get unique items

Comment: Your current way is not the best way to remove duplicates, but to answer the question *as is*, `if i not in uniq: uniq.append(i)`

Comment: @AlexFrolov then why do you ask a question about making a list of unique  items then ???

Comment: there is no such syntax in python. you can have the `if` in one line, and the `else` in the next line

Comment: @fferri There is a ternary operator like `1 if False else True` but the point is it makes no sense here since append is in-place and the else condition is basically not required if the logic is inverted

Comment: `continue` is a **statement**, cannot be in a ternary **expression**.

Comment: @bruno-desthuilliers this is good example in my mind, sorry if not

Comment: @fferri: there is no such syntax in python. I think it is right answer. Thanks to everyone for help, negative result is also the result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no such syntax in Python.

The closest to *one line* you can get is **two** lines:

```
lst = [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]
uniq = []
for i in lst:
    if i not in uniq: uniq.append(i)    # <----
    else: continue                      # <----
    print(str(i))  # other useful code
```

Trying to put everything on one line (`if i not in uniq: uniq.append(i); else: continue`) would give you a syntax error).

The syntax you mentioned (`uniq.append(i) if i not in uniq else continue`) is a ternary *expression*, and as an expression, it cannot contain `continue`, which is a *statement*.